# What is a "double DC power supply"?

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

I'm looking at this amp: 
http://s.aliexpress.com/zY3miYNj

It states it requires:
- Supply voltage: double DC power supply +- 58~ +- 70V.

- Rated output power: 500W (+- 65V power supply.

Any ideas?

Comment: dual rail: negative and positive rails instead of ground and vcc

Comment: So -30v and +30v? And could it run off normal ground and vcc supply?

Comment: -30 and +30 should work, but you'll get more watts from the higher end of the voltage spec on those chip amps. i don't think the linked one can normally be driven w/a single-rail supply. you can make a dual-rail with two isolated single-end supplies; google it.

Comment: @Kiwi It can't work without a COMMON that can both sink current from the (+V) and source current  into the (-V) supplies.   Split positive/negative power supplies have such a common (which is usually called 'ground' and connected to earth ground).   For a simple Vcc-and-ground supply, there is no COMMON at Vcc/2 such as the amplifier requires.

Comment: @Whit3rd thanks, is there a way to convert battery voltage to +V -V  for an amp?

Comment: It is possible to use two batteries to make a split positive/negative supply.   If voltage boost is required, one battery can drive a DC/DC converter with +V/common/-V outputs.   Sometimes the output 'common' is tied to one pole of the DC input.

Answer (score 1):

From the specification:

> - Supply voltage: double DC power supply +- 58~ +- 70V
> - Rated output power: 500W (+- 65V power supply 4ohm load, distortion 10%)
> - If the voltage is over 70V, will damage the board
> - Recommended double power supply -+65V
> - Recommended speaker: 10-18inch 4-8Ohm speaker

Working backwards from the rated output:

- From \$ P = \frac {V^2}{R} \$ we get \$ V = \sqrt { PR} = \sqrt { 500 \cdot 4} = 44 \; V_{RMS} \$

We need to calculate with RMS to work out the peak to peak voltage which will be given by \$ V_{P-P} = 2 \sqrt 2 V_{RMS} = 2 \sqrt 2 44 = 124 \; V_{P-P}\$

To generate this we would need a supply voltage of +/- 62 V plus a few extra for headroom. Given that the spec indicates 70 V max., you don't have a lot of room to manoeuvre.

All this assumes that one speaker terminal is connected to the supply common. If, as would be more common, the amplifier drives the speaker in bridge mode then a single-ended supply could be used and polarity reversal done by the H-bridge. In this case neither speaker terminal is grounded.